# Android MediaPlayer plays no sound and screen is getting black

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

My problem is when I run my app on API level 23 devices,I have a an issue,when video is playing and I lock the device,after unlocking,it plays sound for 2-3 seconds and then there is no sound,and after a couple of seconds the screen is getting black.

**LogCat**

```
09-14 07:56:01.819 1641-1641/system_process E/PowerManagerService-JNI: Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
09-14 07:56:01.919 1641-1641/system_process E/art: DexFile_getDexOptNeeded file '/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar' does not exist
09-14 07:56:02.800 1641-1641/system_process E/ConsumerIrService: Can't open consumer IR HW Module, error: -2
09-14 07:56:02.921 1641-1706/system_process E/EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
09-14 07:56:04.158 1641-1641/system_process E/UsbDeviceManager: failed to write to /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_rndis/ethaddr
09-14 07:56:04.158 1641-1641/system_process E/UsbDeviceManagerJNI: could not open /dev/usb_accessory
09-14 07:56:04.266 1641-1641/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-14 07:56:04.266 1641-1641/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-14 07:56:04.266 1641-1641/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.pattern.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-14 07:56:04.266 1641-1641/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-14 07:56:04.266 1641-1641/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-14 07:56:04.274 1641-1641/system_process E/WifiService: Invoking mWifiStateMachine.setWifiEnabled
09-14 07:56:04.679 1641-1722/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
09-14 07:56:04.684 1641-1722/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
09-14 07:56:04.693 1641-2001/system_process E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found
09-14 07:56:04.702 1641-1641/system_process E/InputMethodManagerService: Ignoring updateSystemUiLocked due to an invalid token. uid:1000 token:null
09-14 07:56:04.725 1641-1641/system_process E/FlpHardwareProvider: Error hw_get_module 'flp': -2
09-14 07:56:04.725 1641-1641/system_process E/LocationManagerService: FLP HAL not supported
09-14 07:56:04.726 1641-1641/system_process E/ActivityRecognitionHardware: Error hw_get_module: -2
09-14 07:56:04.726 1641-1641/system_process E/LocationManagerService: Hardware Activity-Recognition not supported.
09-14 07:56:04.741 1641-1662/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-14 07:56:04.781 1641-1662/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-14 07:56:04.782 1641-1715/system_process E/WifiStateMachine: Failed to reload STA firmware java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: command '16 softap fwreload wlan0 STA' failed with '501 16 SoftAP command has failed'
09-14 07:56:04.784 1641-1715/system_process E/WifiStateMachine: Unable to change interface settings: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '18 interface setcfg wlan0 0.0.0.0 0 down' failed with '400 18 Failed to set address (No such device)'
09-14 07:56:04.784 1641-1715/system_process E/WifiMonitor: killSupplicant p2pfalse init.svc.wpa_supplicant=unknown init.svc.p2p_supplicant=unknown
09-14 07:56:04.902 1641-1641/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
09-14 07:56:04.917 1641-1641/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
09-14 07:56:04.922 1641-1641/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
09-14 07:56:05.328 1641-1717/system_process E/ConnectivityService: Failed to find Messenger in unregisterNetworkFactory
09-14 07:56:06.506 1641-1662/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-14 07:56:06.533 1641-1662/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-14 07:56:06.687 1641-1662/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-14 07:56:06.726 1641-1662/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-14 07:56:06.737 1641-1662/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-14 07:56:06.857 1641-1662/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-14 07:56:06.862 1641-1662/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-14 07:56:10.042 1641-1715/system_process E/WifiHW: Failed to stop supplicant
09-14 07:56:10.042 1641-1715/system_process E/WifiNative-HAL: Could not start hal
09-14 07:56:10.042 1641-1715/system_process E/WifiStateMachine: Failed to start HAL
09-14 07:56:10.042 1641-1715/system_process E/WifiHW: Cannot open "/system/etc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf": No such file or directory
09-14 07:56:10.042 1641-1715/system_process E/WifiHW: Wi-Fi will not be enabled
09-14 07:56:10.042 1641-1715/system_process E/WifiStateMachine: Failed to start supplicant!
09-14 07:56:39.975 1641-1674/system_process E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaaf4b0e0
09-14 07:56:39.975 1641-1674/system_process E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
09-14 07:56:39.990 1641-1715/system_process E/WifiStateMachine:  Fail to set up pno, want false now false
09-14 07:56:39.997 1641-1715/system_process E/WifiStateMachine:  Fail to set up pno, want false now false
09-14 07:56:43.721 1641-1715/system_process E/WifiStateMachine:  Fail to set up pno, want false now false
```

These two line are printed every time when I lock or unlock the device.

```
09-14 07:56:43.721 1641-1715/system_process E/WifiStateMachine:  Fail
to set up pno, want false now false 09-14 08:03:36.788
1641-1674/system_process E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown
buffer: 0xaaf4b0e0
```

Any help is appreciated,thx.

Comment: what API level are you targeting?

Comment: @A.Shevchuk API 25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have fixed the issue in Android 6.0.1. Just update your Android OS version and it will be ok.